# How to dynamically load contents when we scroll down, like Google/Facebook does.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic-data

I have a PHP application which will display articles from the database tables but I don't want to use pagination rather when user scroll down it should load new articles and so on. Just like Google/Facebook does.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial on jQuery Endless/Infinite Scroll and PHP-MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501524/tutorial-on-jquery-endless-infinite-scroll-and-php-mysql)

Comment: This might be of help http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best `infinite scroll` out there, as it works with your pagination.This is the [Link](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll)

Comment: Im using it, for reference see `www.courseworld.org`. If you have alreday done paginaion for your page, it will be a 5min job to integrate it.

Comment: No I don't have pagination, I want to avoid it as it is out fashioned nowadays. Isn't it?

Comment: Nope, you got me wrong friend, It will just convert your already done pagination to scrolling automatically with some customizations. See this link for example `http://www.courseworld.org/home/view_category/2/55/131` :D

Comment: I downloaded their sourcecode, opened their demo file and when I scroll the page am getting javascript error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'ias'** any idea?

Comment: Everything is there, and about your error, run the files in `localhost` not directly. see this link `http://www.courseworld.org/home/view_category/2/55/131`.

Comment: I downloaded required CSS/JS and put it locally and it worked. But I have one more concern here, 2nd page was already created here and this jquery appended it when we scrolled. So if we have 100 pages to show do we need to create 100 pages in advanced? or we can dynamically created and display as and when needed? What was your approach on it?

Comment: URL you mentioned is working great, exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

handle the scroll event, make an ajax call to a php file that will send back a json or a html string to append directly, animate it a bit to make it look smooth