# Page scroll using Jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to add some functionality to my page when it is completely scrolled down.
can any one tell is the any way to find whether the page is completely scrolled down using Jquery?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837741/jquery-detecting-reaching-bottom-of-scroll-doesnt-work-only-detects-the-top

This should anwser it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if(($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop()) == $(window).height()){
       //Scroll reached at the bottom 
   }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Meabh/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) is the right tool for the job. There are several demos highlighting the event driven model that Waypoints utilizes.

Answer (score 0):

for scroll mapping, u can use this;

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
   //console.log(scrollVal);

   if ( scrollVal > 0 && scrollVal < 100 ){
     //code
   }else if ( scrollVal > 100 && scrollVal < 200 ) {
     //code
   }else{ //bigger than 200px
     //code
   }

});
```