# Explain why scrollTop() always returns 0 here

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGqPNz

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
  $('body').bind("scroll", function () {
    if ($('body').scrollTop()) {
      console.log('triggered!');
    } else {
      console.log($('body').scrollTop());
    }
  });
```

The scroll event is firing on the body element. The scroll bar is on the body element, not on the html or the window element. So why does document.body.scrollTop or $('body').scrollTop() return 0?

Is there any way I can detect the scroll bar position with this or am I stuck if I want to use height: 100%; overflow:hidden on the html element?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a webkit bug. Works with Firefox. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423935

Comment: Thanks! I set body to overflow-y hidden and added a wrapper div with height 100 and overflow-y auto, and the scroll event / scrollTop works on the div.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Shikkediel's comment, it appears to be a Webkit bug. If you put a div immediately inside the body, and bind the scroll event to the div, it works.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVderq

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.scroll-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.scroll-wrapper').bind("scroll", function () {
  if ($('.scroll-wrapper').scrollTop()) {
    console.log('triggered!');
    console.log($('.scroll-wrapper').scrollTop());
  } else {
    console.log($('.scroll-wrapper').scrollTop());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have `overflow-y: hidden;`. Remove this and then `scrollTop()` will work